# Is it legal to extend a "new" instance using underscore _.extend

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Of course it's legal to do the following:

```
_.extend({name: 'moe'}, {age: 50});
=> {name: 'moe', age: 50}
```

Is it legal (and won't cause future problems) if I _.extend two (or more) instances that were created with new?

as in:

```
var a = new Block();
var b = new Wood();
_.extend(a,b);
```

Comment: I'd say you shouldn't, as the extend function is probably meant for regular objects, but an instance of a function would be an object as well, as everything is an object, so in many cases it will probably work, until it suddenly doesn't for some reason. In reality I have no idea how the extend function works un underscore, so I could be wrong ?

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/underscore-extend.html may interest you

Answer (score 2):

This is the `_extend` function ([source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-84)):

```
_.extend = function(obj) {
    each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
      if (source) {
        for (var prop in source) {
          obj[prop] = source[prop];
        }
      }
    });
    return obj;
};
```

In your case, `_.extend(a,b)` will run

```
if (b) { // true
    for (var prop in b) {
        a[prop] = b[prop];
    }
}
```

Note that a `for in` loop iterates over all enumerable properties, even those that come from the prototype (not own).

I don't know if that's what you want or not.

It could produce some problems, for example in case there are properties named equal:

```
Block.prototype.foo = function(){ return this.bar; }
Block.prototype.bar = true;
Wood.prototype.bar = false;
```

If you extend `a` with `b`, `bar` will be overridden. Then, if you call `a.foo`, it will expect `a.bar` to be `true`, but it will be `false`. That can cause unexpected errors in `foo`.

Comment: I tested and it seems to work fine, but I just wanted to check if anyone knows that it is in fact a valid operation to _extend an instance of .... as all of the examples I find online are for object literals, and never of an instance with an instance!

Comment: @user2040670 Yes, it's a valid operation. But use it carefully!